# Open multiple custom binary files with polars lazy API

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

For an data analysis tool I am developing, I need to be capable to read an automotive binary file format using python (MDF4) and then to do computation on the read data (mean values, RMS values, min/max of currents, voltages, temperatures). A standard data set is about 400 GB stored in about 5000 files.

I am aware of the asammdf Python package as well of other licensed solution from multiples companies (like Vector). The problem is that the data I need to open to do analysis is bigger than the 64 GB RAM capacity of my laptop (or on any computer I am currently using).

I am also aware about Dask, PySpark, Arrow, pandas2 and polars. All technologies seems to be able to do OLAP on data-bigger-than-the-memory from what I read. There is so much to try, so I decided to start with polars.

Polars could be a good candidate:

- it use Arrow2 in the background
- as an DataFrame API analog to pandas
- the lazy-evaluation could be able to handle the standard data set size we need to analyze on one laptop / computer

**The question is:**
Is there a possibility to extend the Lazy API of polars to read directly the data from the MDF files into DataFrame and do lazy-evaluation?

Comment: Not something I've used but I found https://github.com/ratal/mdfr which seems to have methods for exporting to polars. It may be of interest if you haven't seen it.